# ClassCastException thrown at Runtime

Tags: java, exception, classcastexception

I've been working on this simple Java program and at a point it throws a "ClassCastException" and I can't figure out why. What happens in the program is, it reads out of 2 text files and store them in Object `Arraylists` (Because I use the same method to read both files)

Later when I try to cast those objects to the custom data types I've made, the program throws this error. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void staffFunctions() {
    ArrayList<Object> staffs = TextFileHandler.readFile(staffText,userState);

    for(Object obj: staffs) {
        Staff staff = (Staff) obj;
        if (staff.getUsername().equals(username) && staff.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            staffMenu(staff);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Username/Password Invalid.");
        }
    }
```

}

^^That calls for the Staff related menu.

```
            ArrayList<Object> clients = TextFileHandler.readFile(accText, userState);
        System.out.print("Enter Client Username > ");
                    String usernameClient = input.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter amount > ");
                    int amount = input.nextInt();

                    for(Object objs: clients) {
                        Customer customer = (Customer) objs;
                        if(customer.getUsername().equals(usernameClient)){
                            ClientFunctions.withdraw(customer, username, amount);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Client Username!");
                        }
                    }
```

^^Here's where I get the exception, exactly at "Customer customer = (Customer) objs;"

I have two Classes Customer and Staff. And it throws "**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Staff cannot be cast to Customer**", at run time. Compile time there are no issues.

readFile Method //Update

```
public static ArrayList<Object> readFile(String fileName, int userState) {
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<Object> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        fileReader = new java.io.FileReader("src/" + fileName);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String element[] = line.split(" ");
            if (userState == 1) {
                Customer customer = new Customer(element[1], element[3], element[5], element[7], element[9], element[11]);
                elements.add(customer);
            } else {
                Staff staff = new Staff(element[1], element[3]);
                elements.add(staff);
            }
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
    }

    return elements;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the concrete type of the elements in `staffs` *at runtime?* The JVM is telling you that, whatever they are, **they're not `Staff` instances.**

Comment: I didn't understand what you said Matt, sorry.

Comment: Please edit your question to show how clients is filled. Obviously, it has Staff objects in it. I'd recommend to change your code so that clients isn't a list of objects. This is hard to understand.

Comment: What the error mean is that you have `Staff` in the collection `clients`  I suggest you have a look at what your program is doing in your debugger to see what this is the case.

Comment: @NimilaHiranya something like ArrayList<Object> is not a good practice. It is a "list of everything possible". That means you'll be in trouble if you have code like "Customer customer = (Customer) objs;" because it expects an element of type Customer.

Comment: @tilman-hausherr Updated it. :)

Comment: Next thing now is to tell what happens in TextFileHandler.readFile(accText, userState) - obviously, it returns a list that doesn't just have Customer objects, but something else, too.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Added! :)

Comment: Ok... now the next thing to watch for is, what's in the "userstate"? Because that influences what object type elements are created.  I'd also recommend that you learn to use the debugger of your IDE, single step and look at the variables. So that you know whats "happening under the hood".

Comment: Fixed it guys. Thank you! :D

Comment: @TilmanHausherr As you said, having Objects was a bad idea. So I divided the function into two so it serves 2 ArrayLists of corresponding data types. That solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have only two type of data type (`Staff` and `Customer`)at your `Object` lists - `staffs` or `clients` , before type casting you can use the `instanceof` operator, like this -

```
for( Object obj : staffs){

   if(obj instance of Staff){
      Staff staff = (Staff) obj;
   }

   if(obj instance of Customer){
      Customer Customer = (Customer) obj;
   }
   ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Object> clients = TextFileHandler.readFile(accText, userState);
```

So `clients` contains elements of `Object` type.

Inside the for-loop, when you try to cast `objs` (which is of `Object` type) to `Customer`, ClassCastException occurs.

```
Customer customer = (Customer) objs;
```

For the casting to be successful, you must make sure that
the object to be cast is an instance of the subclass. If the superclass object is not an instance
of the subclass, a runtime ClassCastException occurs. This can be made sure by using `instanceof` operator.

Here's an example to make things more clear:

```
Object o = new Circle();
(Circle)o.getRadius(); // No exception at this point
```

There's no Exception. The reason is, `o` concrete type is Circle.

Now your case is somewhat like:

```
Object o;
(Circle)o.getRadius(); // Exception is thrown at this line
```